# Another bitmap's sizes

Tags: android, android-drawable, autoresize

I added bitmap image to drawable folder with 64x64 sizes. Then I get a reference to this by `Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.brick);` The problem is in output I get an image with 128x128 sizes. I dont use any `BitmapFactory.Options`. Why it happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I added bitmap image to drawable folder with 64x64 sizes

I am going to assume that you mean this literally, and you put the images in `res/drawable/`. That is a synonym for `res/drawable-mdpi/`.

> The problem is in output I get an image with 128x128 sizes.

That would occur if your device is an `-xhdpi` device. Android will resample the drawable from `-mdpi` (~160dpi) to `-xhdpi` (~320dpi).

Try moving your image to `res/drawable-nodpi/`.

Comment: CommonsWare, i have a question regarding NetBeans IDE's error while building apk. Can you check it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041658/netbeans-clean-build-android-error-java-lang-x500principal-access